# Как получить элемент через ref?

Tags: angular

выдает undefined сейчас........ https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kgsdez?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Используй вместо `ngOnInit` `ngAfterViewInit`

Документация: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview

Демо: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kgsdez?file=src/app/app.component.ts